# working with acl.h - undefined reference to `acl_init' error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, acl, undefined-reference

I want write simple C program to set ACL to one particular file on Linux. My starting code is trying to use function from "acl.h". I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, I've installed "Access control list utilities" - "acl 2.2.52-1". Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/acl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {     
 acl_t aclvar;
 int count = 1;   
 aclvar = acl_init(count);
 return 0;
}
```

The problem is, that I get error while compiling with "gcc myAcl.c" or "gcc -lacl myAcl.c":

```
/tmp/cc5sVzSR.o: In function `main':
myAcl.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `acl_init'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Look at the answer by nos and try to understand the importance and differences between a headerfile and a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries you link to needs to come last

```
gcc  myAcl.c -lacl
```